# Bot doesn't connect with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

so in the past few days I wanted to start my Discord Bot (I made no changes) to test something and I got this Error:

```
querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.pnqjgso.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.pnqjgso.mongodb.net'
}
```

I tried it everyday for the past week, but no success. The password and User is correct, I can connect with the same string in the Mongo Compass. Also my internet connection should not be the problem, it's wired and normally works fine.

Does someone know a solution for this Problem? Thanks for every answer.

PS: I tried to use an older connection string but they won't work either because they're deprecated. I also sent the Code to my friends who live far away from me and they got the same error, so it can't be locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is a DNS failure, `EREFUSED` indicates the DNS server refused the query.

You could try contacting whoever runs your DNS service, or try using another DNS provider, like Google (8.8.8.8)

Comment: I tried to change it but it didn't worked, so I asked 2 friends (Both live far away from me) to test it if it works for them but they get the same error, any Ideas?

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward, your app is sending a DNS resolution request, and the DNS server is responding "No, I will not resolve that for you".  There isn't much you can change to fix that, other than using a different DNS server or talking to the people that run the server you are using.

Comment: Okay I tried a different DNS for the third time and now I don't get this error anymore but a deprecation warning that looks like this:

[MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.